# Use The Selected value of the CASE WHEN inside the WHERE Clause

Tags: sql-server

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT date,
    CASE WHEN h_score > v_score
    THEN
        ho_t_id
    ELSE
        v_t_id
    END
FROM Games
```

I would like to use the selected value (of the CASE WHEN statement) inside the WHERE clause.
I try to do something like that:

```
SELECT date,
    CASE WHEN h_score > v_score
    THEN
        ho_t_id
    ELSE
        v_t_id
    END AS T
FROM Games
WHERE T = '1234'
```

This (of course) doesn't work.

How can I do that?

Thank you !

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server. Pick one.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (your query here) AS X WHERE T = '1234'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT date, T FROM (
    SELECT date,
        CASE WHEN h_score > v_score
        THEN
            ho_t_id
        ELSE
            v_t_id
        END AS T
    FROM Games
) g
WHERE g.T = '1234'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can have your query inside a CTE and have the where clause out side.

```
with cte 
as
(
    SELECT date,
           CASE 
           WHEN h_score > v_score
           THEN ho_t_id
           ELSE v_t_id
           END AS T
    FROM Games
)
select * from cte where T = '1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply repeat `CASE` in `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT date,
    CASE WHEN h_score > v_score
    THEN
        ho_t_id
    ELSE
        v_t_id
    END AS T
FROM Games
WHERE (CASE WHEN h_score > v_score
    THEN
        ho_t_id
    ELSE
        v_t_id
    END) = '1234'
```